# массив байтов (изображения) не удается полностью получить от сервера клиенту

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Отправляю серверу изображение в массиве байт. Сервер успешно получает данные, отправляю обратно клиенту, а вот клиент получает небольшой его кусок, а не все данные. Как решить проблему?

Это клиентский код:

```
public async Task<byte[]> UploadAsync(byte[] buffer)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8080/");
        request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        request.GetRequestStream().Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        int bufferLength = (int)request.GetResponse().ContentLength;
        buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
        await request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream().ReadAsync(buffer, 0, bufferLength);

        return buffer;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Это серверный:

```
private async Task HandleContextAsync(HttpListenerContext listenerContext)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)listenerContext.Request.ContentLength64];
    listenerContext.Request.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);           

    listenerContext.Response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
    listenerContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
    await listenerContext.Response.OutputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка здесь:

```
await request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream().ReadAsync(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
```

Нет **никакой** гарантии, что ответ придёт одним куском. Вы не можете просто так игнорировать возвбращаемое значение `ReadAsync`. Читайте в цикле до победного:

```
using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    var readSoFar = 0;
    while (readSoFar < bufferLength)
    {
        var actuallyRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, readSoFar, bufferLength - readSoFar);
        if (actuallyRead == 0)
            throw new КакойТоException("сервер недослал файл");
        readSoFar += actuallyRead;
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую!)

Comment: Да, все правильно работает, спасибо большое!

Comment: @БобровСаша: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй в клиентском коде дождаться записи всех данных:

```
Task.Run(async() => {
  await request.GetRequestStream().Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); 
});
```

Таким образом сервер должен получить всю порцию данных

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!) Попробую напишу